# ng-options is creating more select boxes

Tags: angularjs

I got this:

```
<div ng-repeat="candle in candles">
    <div >
       <select ng-repeat="object in candle "><option value="{{ object.id }}"> {{ object.name }}</option></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have to use the **ng-repeat** twice to get to the objects but angular is creating for each object a select box. 
I just want it to create one select box with all options.

Let's say I got 3 elements in that object.
Basically angular is creating more select boxes like that:

---

### select box

---

### select box

---

### select box

But I want just one select box with all the 3 elements as options.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ng-repeat should come inside the option tag

Comment: @user3217843 Could you please create an answer so I can accept it? Turns out you got right.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on creating the select options using `ng-repeat` then you must apply the `ng-repeat` on the `option` element instead of the `select`:

```
<div ng-repeat="candle in candles">
    <div>
        <select>
           <option ng-repeat="object in candle"
                   value="{{object.id}}">{{object.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```